# Why does ActiveMQ Artemis throw error while adding users?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have created an instance of ActiveMQ Artemis 2.25.0. When creating the instance I provided a user called "adminuser". I can see that this is available in `artemis-users.properties`. Now I am trying to add users using the CLI. The command that I used is

```
./artemis user add --user adminuser --password xyz --user-command-user guest --user-command-password guest --role admin
```

Please note that I am in the `bin` of the instance. As per the specs I also kept the instance running. I get the below error.

```
Connection brokerURL = tcp://localhost:61615
Connection failed::AMQ229031: Unable to validate user from /127.0.0.1:59843. Username: adminuser; SSL certificate subject DN: unavailable
Exception in thread "main" ActiveMQSecurityException[errorType=SECURITY_EXCEPTION message=AMQ229031: Unable to validate user from /127.0.0.1:59844. Username: adminuser; SSL certificate subject DN: unavailable]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:554)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:446)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.createSessionContext(ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.java:306)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.createSessionContext(ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.java:254)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSessionChannel(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1419)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSessionInternal(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:736)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSession(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:328)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.AbstractAction.performCoreManagement(AbstractAction.java:36)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.user.AddUser.add(AddUser.java:52)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.commands.user.AddUser.execute(AddUser.java:42)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.internalExecute(Artemis.java:160)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:108)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.cli.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:135)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.execute(Artemis.java:134)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis.main(Artemis.java:50)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is happening because you're providing the incorrect password for the `adminUser` (i.e. `xyz`) when running the `user add` command. Notice that the error message says (in part):

```
Unable to validate user from /127.0.0.1:59844. Username: adminuser
```

If I create and run a fresh instance of ActiveMQ Artemis 2.25.0 using:

```
$ ./artemis create userTest --user adminUser --password adminPassword --require-login
$ cd userTest/bin/
$ ./artemis run
```

Then I can add a user like so using the previously defined credentials (i.e. `adminUser` & `adminPassword`):

```
$ ./artemis user add --user adminUser --password adminPassword --user-command-user myUser --user-command-password myPassword --role myRole
Connection brokerURL = tcp://localhost:61616
myUser added successfully.
```

It's important to note that by default the CLI will try to parse the `acceptor` named "artemis" from the instance's `broker.xml` and use that for its URL. If it can't parse that information then it will use `tcp://localhost:61616`. You can control these two things manually via the `--acceptor` and `--url` options respectively. If you have modified your `broker.xml` from the default it may be better to manually specify `--url` on your CLI commands.

It's also worth noting that if you've configured high availability with a pair of brokers (e.g. using replication or a shared store) you won't be able to add users to the backup since it won't actually be active to receive any connections from the CLI for management. If you want to manage users on a HA pair of brokers you should use the [Basic Security Manager](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/security.html#basic-security-manager) instead since it is designed for this use-case. Although LDAP would be even better.

Comment: I am using the password that I used while creating the instance. It's the same password. I copy pasted it. --password xyz is the adminuser password. Am I not getting something here?

Comment: I just added steps demonstrating how to do this successfully. I'm not sure what you're doing that's different from what I did.

Comment: I did the same. Could it be because I am using a clustered instance?

Comment: Did you do the _exact_ same thing as I did and still received the security error? If not, could you provide steps (like I did) to reproduce the failure? If your instance is clustered you're almost certainly not doing the same thing I'm doing.

Comment: Tested all combinations. It seems that when I have static connectors for clustering, I encounter this issue. I removed the static clustering and it works now.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. In short, I think you should use `--url` on your commands with the proper URL rather than letting the CLI try to figure it out.

Comment: Further observations. This time I was not using static connectors for clustering. I was able to add user to the master but not the slave. When I killed the master and slave was the live broker, I was able to add user to it. Please note I was using replication for HA.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your most recent comment. In short, not being able to add users on a backup is expected.